# Failed to compare Immutable-js objects

Tags: javascript, chai, immutable.js, chai-immutable

I'm trying to understand why my simple chai (using chai-immutable) test fails.

```
it('should work', () => {
   var currentState = Immutable.fromJS({
     name: 'myName',
     age: 20,
     friends: []
   });

   var newState = currentState.merge({
     name: 'someOtherName',
     age: 30
   });

   expect(newState).to.equal(Immutable.fromJS({
     name: 'someOtherName',
     age: 30,
     friends: []
   }));
});
```

- If I'm using mergeDeep instead of merge - it still doesn't work
- If I compare the .toJS() eveluation of both expected and actual values (using lodash isEqual) - It works...

What am I doing wrong? I guess I'm missing something stupid...

Thanks,
Amit.

Comment: What happens if you change the `Immutable.fromJS()` calls to `Immutable.Map()`?

Comment: Same thing... the same error: AssertionError: expected { Object (size, _root, ...) } to equal { Object (size, _root, ...) }

Comment: Try converting them to Immutable.Map like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913458/immutable-js-compare-nested-structures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try comparing the two with [Immutable.is()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/is):

```
let checkThis = Immutable.fromJS({
   name: 'someOtherName',
   age: 30,
   friends: []
 });
Immutable.is(newState, checkThis)//true
```

Comment: Immutable.is(newState, checkThis) works, but it seems that to.equal is also mapped to use Immutable.is function and still fails. BTW, replacing to.equal with to.eql solved this issue, however I don't understand why....

Answer (score 2):

Well, it turns out I made an embarrassing mistake - I imported the wrong Immutable module...

My code looked like this:

```
import {fromJS} from 'Immutable';
```

Instead of:

```
import {fromJS} from 'immutable';
```

Notice the capital I.

Oh well...

Comment: You should mark this answer as resolving your issue then :)