# Immutable js : how to compare List with same contents and different ordered?

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

I am trying to compare different orderd List of Immutable js. 
I thought "equals" would be work, but it is only true when is same order.

is there any way to compare for containing same content?

```js
var list1 = Immutable.List.of({a:1},2,{b:3},4);
var list2 = Immutable.List.of(2,{a:1},4,{b:3});
console.log(list1.equals(list2)) //false
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913458/immutable-js-compare-nested-structures

Comment: Before you edited the 2 lists, you could have done `list1.isSubset(list2) && list1.isSuperset(list2)`

Comment: @AnthonyZ thansk that is exactly what I want to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. by definition, order is essential to lists
2. Two ordinary Javascript objects are never equal to each other, even if they have the same contents.

You could, however, do this:

```
const set1 = Immutable.Set.of(Immutable.Map({a:1}),2,Immutable.Map({b:3}),4);
const set2 = Immutable.Set.of(2,Immutable.Map({a:1}),4,Immutable.Map({b:3}));
console.log(set1.equals(set2)) //true
```

Nota bene: using `var` with an immutable *defeats the entire purpose!* . Use `const`.